# C_ISAM file parsing with ruby or perl

Tags: ruby, perl

Does anybody had success parsing *.idx and *.dat files with ruby or perl? I have an old application, without the source code and i want to parse files generated by this legacy code.

Any direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) does throw up a few [modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=isam&mode=all)

The top possibilities are:

- [CIsam](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CIsam/)
- [Isam](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Isam/)

However these are both circa 2000 and are failing tests.  Here are reports from [CPAN Testers](http://www.cpantesters.org/) for these modules:

- [CIsam test reports](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/C/CIsam.html)
- [Isam test reports](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/I/Isam.html)

So YMMV with these modules but it may give you the leg up u need?

Comment: As I see, CIsam/Isam require some external library with isam.h.

Comment: that's exactly my problem. you need an Informix/IBM non-free lib. I know how to use search.cpan.org as well :-)

Comment: Ah but u don't mention that you tried and/or looked at CIsam or Isam modules on CPAN in your question so we're none the wiser :(